# Relationship of eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$, where $B=MAM$ and $M$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Write $A$ and $B$ as two $n\times n$ symmetric matrices, where $B=MAM$ and $M$ is diagonal. Let $V_A$ and $V_B$ be the eigenvector matrices of $A$ and $B$. Is $V_A V_B'$ a function of $M$?

Comment: Should we also assume $M$ is nonsingular?

Comment: @hardmath yes. $M$ is nonsingular.

Comment: Saying that $V_A,V_B$ are "the eigenvector matrices" of $A,B$ does not precisely characterize them.  Perhaps you have in mind that these are orthogonal matrices that diagonalize $A,B$ ?  If you want $V_AV_B'$ to be "a function of $M$", then for each $M$ there should be exactly one matrix product $V_AV_B'$.  I don't see that we have enough information to prove such a claim.